# converting to kotling DSL the defines under buildSrc got error Could not get unknown property which is defined in the buildSrc folder kts

Tags: groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Trying to convert to use kotlin DSL.
In the buildSrc folder added the following `buildSrc/src/main/java/Versions.kt` file:

```
object DepVersions {
    const val supportlib = "28.0.0"
    const val androidBuild  = "7.4.1"  //AGP
    
......
    // test dependencies
    const val robolectric   = "4.8.1"
    const val jacoco        = "0.8.8"
    const val junitVersion  = "4.13.2"
......    
}
```

`build.gradle.kts` in `buildSrc/src`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

and in the root level build.gradle (simplified)

```
// Top-level build
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
       
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${DepVersions.androidBuild}" //<=== got error
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${DepVersions.kotlin}" //<== eror
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:${DepVersions.jacoco}" //<== eror
......
    }
}
```

when do sync, the line `${DepVersions.androidBuild}"` got error `Could not get unknown property 'DepVersions'`:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'DepVersions' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.getProperty(ConfigureDelegate.java:130)
```

But when clicking on `DepVersions.androidBuild` it opens the file `Versions.kt` and seems resolve to the define.

[image]

---

**Update:**

As pointed out by @aSemy, the `build.gradle.kts` should be under `buildSrc/` after doing that the `unknown property DepVersions` error is gone.

But still not able to convert the script so that the build.gradle could be converted to build.gradle.kts, as listed below.

---

Also tried convert this `build.gradle` to `build.gradle.kts`

when converted to build.gradle.kts, there are some scripts just dont know how to convert

```
in build.gradle

    plugins.withId("jacoco") {
        tasks.withType(Test) { task ->
            task.jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
            jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
        }
    }


    task coverageCheck(type:Exec) {
        group "verification"
        description "Run coverage evolution check"

        workingDir proj.rootDir
        environment "BASE_COVERAGE_FILE_ENV", System.getenv("BASE_COVERAGE_FILE_ENV")

        executable "codecoverage/cc_compare_update_sd4"
        args getCoverageArgs()
    }
```

the first one tried with

```
in the converted build.gradle.kts

    plugins.withId("jacoco") {
        tasks.withType<Test>() {
            jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true. //<=== got error
            jacoco.excludes = ["jdk.internal.*"]
        }
    }
```

it got error `Unresolved reference`:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public val PluginDependenciesSpec.jacoco: PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

the

```
./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-08-05 21:17:56 UTC
Revision:     d1daa0cbf1a0103000b71484e1dbfe096e095918

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          19.0.1 (Eclipse Adoptium 19.0.1+10)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.2.1 aarch64
```

Comment: _"`build.gradle.kts` in `buildSrc/src`"_ — What is the exact location of the buildSrc Gradle build file? Is it `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`, or `buildSrc/src/build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: _"added the following `buildSrc/src/main/java/Versions.kt` file"_ — Are you sure the location of this file is correct? It's a Kotlin file, but the path is `main/java`. Shouldn't it be the Kotlin source directory, `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Versions.kt`?

Comment: It might help to update your answer to include the version of Gradle you are using (`./gradlew --version`), and the output of `./gradlew assemble`

Comment: Thanks @aSemy, you're right it should be `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` and error is gone after correct it (tried main/java and main/kotlin both are ok). But still not be able to convert the scripts in the top level build.gradle if make it a kts. I updated the question. Any suggestion there?

Comment: [There's a guide on task-specific JaCoCo configuration in the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_specific_task_configuration), with both Kotlin and Groovy examples